# Adding a custom icon (for a hand written script) to notification area xfce

Tags: xfce, notification

I don't use unity, and I wrote a simple script to start programs used in recording audio. (Jack, guitarix, etc) I would like to know is there a command that will allow me to create an icon in the notification area of XFCE 4's panel? Also can I use this icon to kill all PID's created by the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
qjackctl -s &
jackPID=$!
env sleep 2s
guitarix &
guitarixPID=$!

#kill $jackPID & kill $guitarixPID
exit
```

i already have the PID's stored to local variables, but these can easily be written to a file if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Yad](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/yad-zenity-on-steroids-display.html), an advanced Zenity fork. It supports [systray notification icons](https://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/NotificationIcon) and can be installed from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager).